# Skip image url when HTTP Error appears in csv file

Tags: python, urllib, http-error

I have a project trying to imagescrape from a website. I use a csv file with all the urls. Some urls i dont have the premission to open(or they dont exist). I get a Http error 403 in phyton from those. I just want the try the next url in the csv file and ignore the error.

```python
import urllib.request
import csv

with open ('urls_01.csv') as images:
    images = csv.reader(images)
    img_count = 1
    for image in images:
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(image[0],
                'images/image_{0}.jpg'.format(img_count)) 
        img_count += 1
```

This is the error

```python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Heigre\Documents\Phyton\img_test.py", line 8, in <module>
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(image[0],
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 241, in urlretrieve
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 216, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 525, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 634, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 563, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 496, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 643, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if the import is needed, but I provided it based on your error output. Also provided an idea of a print statement that might help if you need only pass on specific errors…

```
import urllib.request
from urllib.error import HTTPError
import csv

with open ('urls_01.csv') as images:
    images = csv.reader(images)
    img_count = 1
    for image in images:
        try:
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(
                image[0],
                'images/image_{0}.jpg'.format(img_count)
            ) 
            img_count += 1
        except HTTPError as ex:
            # This will catch and hide any HTTPError the below print not tested...
            # print(ex, ex.code)
            pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a try block to catch the http error:

```html
import urllib.request
import csv

with open ('urls_01.csv') as images:
    images = csv.reader(images)
    img_count = 1
    for image in images:
        try:
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(image[0],
                    'images/image_{0}.jpg'.format(img_count)) 
            img_count += 1
        except HTTPError:
            pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a try block to catch the http error:

```
    import urllib.request
    import csv

    with open ('urls_01.csv') as images:
        images = csv.reader(images)
        img_count = 1
        for image in images:
            try:
                urllib.request.urlretrieve(image[0],
                        'images/image_{0}.jpg'.format(img_count)) 
                img_count += 1
            except HTTPError:
                pass
```